# Autotest with Rspec2 in Rails 3 Can't Find Binaries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, autotest

I'm trying to get autotest back up and running after moving my project to rails 3.  After upgrading to rspec 2.0.0.beta.22, I can't seem to run autotest.  I get the following:

```
bundler: command not found: c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0.beta.22/bin/rspec
```

even though the binary does in fact exist in that location.

Here is my Gemfile contents:

```
group :development do
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>=2.0.0.beta.22'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
  gem 'autotest'
end

group :test do
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>=2.0.0.beta.22'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
  gem 'autotest'
end
```

and I have the following gems installed (among others):

- autotest (4.3.2)
- autotest-growl (0.2.5)
- rspec (2.0.0.beta22)
- rspec-core (2.0.0.beta22)
- rspec-expectations (2.0.0.beta22)
- rspec-mocks (2.0.0.beta22)
- rspec-rails (2.0.0.beta22)
- ZenTest (4.4.0)

Any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: Rails 3 is not compatible with Ruby 1.9.1. Why do you use it ?

Comment: I am using ruby 1.9.2, confusingly, the install goes under the gems 1.9.1 directory.  If that's not standard, please let me know and I'll look into changing it.

Comment: does plain old "rspec" command run on your windows ?

Comment: Yes rspec alone works just fine, it's only in autotest that it gets messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I remedied the issue:

I uninstalled all testing gems (rspec, factory_girl, webrat, etc).  I then upgraded to rspec 2.0.1, uninstalled ZenTest (in favor of straight autotest).  All of these installations were done outside of the bundler.

I have the following gem setup:

```
autotest (4.4.1)
autotest-growl (0.2.6)
factory_girl (1.3.2)
factory_girl_rails (1.0)
rspec (2.0.1)
rspec-core (2.0.1)
rspec-expectations (2.0.1)
rspec-mocks (2.0.1)
rspec-rails (2.0.1)
webrat (0.7.1)
```

I used the following in the Gemfile.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec', '>=2.0.1'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>=2.0.1'
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using JRuby ( with Rails 3) and I need to put the following in my PATH to fix this issue: jruby-1.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin

You should do something similar for your Ruby on Rails installation.

Comment: I will try messing with the PATH variable a bit, but since the 'bundle exec' call has the direct path to the binary, why would it need to be added to my PATH variable?

Comment: I added my gems bin folder to my PATH and it didn't fix the problem :-/